# Объясните куски кода

Tags: unity3d, c#-8.0

[image: тут приведен код]
**Приветствую прохожу курс по Unity 3d и столкнулся с данным кодом, в целом мне понятен вывод кода, но не понятно какой кусок за что отвечает, помогите пожалуйста разобраться! Спасибо!**

Comment: Пожалуйста, не добавляйте код и/или ошибки в виде скриншотов. Неудобно читать, невозможно копировать. Добавьте текстом в вопрос (кнопка [edit])

Answer (score 0):

скрипт висит на объекте, который нужно отображать через 5 сек
вначале старте получаем ссылки на рендер(отображение) объекта и его риджибоди.
выключаем рендер(, и гравитацию.
в апдейте через 5 секунд включаем рендер, и гравитацию.